# Can you connect to a database on another pc?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I'm using MySQLdb for python, and I would like to connect to a database hosted on an other PC on the same network/LAN.
I tried the followings for host:

```
192.168.5.37  
192.168.5.37:3306  
http://192.168.5.37
http://192.168.5.37:3306
```

None of the above work, I always get the

> 2005, Unknown MySQL server host ... (0)

What might be the problem?

Code:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="192.168.5.37", user = "root" passwd = "password", db = "test1")
```

Comment: Well, certainly `http://` does not help. What makes you think that MySQL uses the HTTP protocol? Can you `ping 192.168.5.37` from a terminal on your local machine?

Comment: I tried pinging it several times, I got a response each time.

Comment: How does your connection set-up look like. please post some code

Comment: try nmap 192.168.5.37 -p 3306 to see if this port is open

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect on remote MySQL database through Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972867/connect-on-remote-mysql-database-through-python)

Comment: I updated the post with some code

Comment: If Tom Ron's command shows the port is open, next try to actually connect through the mysql command, `mysql -h 192.168.5.37 -u root -p -D test1`. See if it works.

Comment: It says it closed, alltough mysql is running on it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MySQL Connector/Python`, a standardized database driver for Python.
You must provide username, password, host, database name.

```
import mysql.connector

conn = mysql.connector.connect(user=username, password=password,
                          host="192.168.5.37",
                          database=databaseName)
conn.close()
```

You can download it from: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/

Answer (score -1):

The IP you posted are **local IPs**
Give it a try with your external IP (for example on this website)
https://www.whatismyip.com/

If it works with the external IP, then it's maybe a misconfiguration of your firewall.

Comment: Not helpful at all. He said the machines are on the same network. Also, a "local IP" would be 127.0.0.1.