# Mysql database accessing between two or more computers python app

Tags: python, mysql

How can I access the mysql database from another machine on a peer to peer network, I have to try and do a lot of research but still don't have a clear understanding of getting that done yet.
I have made python app with MySQL running them on the same machine and ran perfectly.

Comment: Related: [Connect on remote MySQL database through Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972867/connect-on-remote-mysql-database-through-python) / [Can you connect to a database on another pc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33805904/can-you-connect-to-a-database-on-another-pc)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect on remote MySQL database through Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972867/connect-on-remote-mysql-database-through-python)