# How to connect to my remote SQL server

Tags: python, linux, server

I have a linux ubuntu server that I rent from DigitalOcean for storing streaming real time data in MySQL by coding with python.

Problem is that I am coding not in the linux server environment but in my local computer python(personal Windows 10(not a server)). So in the coding, I need to connect to my linux server in order to feed/get the data to/from the linux MySQL server.

I know I need to use MySQLdb library in python to do this. I tried to connect to my linux server by using this MySQLdb in python, but it could not connect to the server.

A different question:
For granting other ip addresses from which I am connect to the mysql server, should I do it whenever my ip address changes? for example, when I work at home I need to grant my home internet ip, and when I work other places do I need to grant that ip addresses?

Anyway, I tried granting to the ip address where I am connecting to the internet, but even after the granting  I cannot access to the mysql server.4

What should I do?

Here is the code I used;

```
import MySQLdb


conn = MySQLdb.connect("000.000.000.0", "root", "password", "name of database")
```

"000.000.000.0" is the server that I rent and it is a linux server.
"root" is my username of the server
"password" is the password for the server as well as for the mysql.
 and then the name of the database I want to connect to.

```
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("SELECT * FROM practice")
```

here I just want to see what's in the "practice" table that I have made in the database.

```
rows = c.fetchall()

for eachRow in rows:
    print eachRow
```

I don;t know what went wrong. 
For Granting I used following code:

```
 GRANT ALL ON nwn.* TO new_username@'00.000.000.00' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';
```

The ip address 00.000.000.000 is Starbucks ip address where I am working on this project right now.I got a message like this:

```
 Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.03 sec)
```

After that I tried to connect in python on my local window python.And it didn't work and got this python error:

```
OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '000.000.000.0' (10061)")
```

What's wrong with this?

Comment: please post the code with which to attempted to connect and the error message if any

Comment: I have posted my code here please take a look.

Comment: Just to be sure '000.000.000.0' is only a placeholder for  a real IP Adress ?!

[Here](https://www.whatismyip.com/what-is-my-public-ip-address/?iref=home) you can find out your current public IP-Adress

Comment: Yes. 000.000.000.0 is the place holder for my Linux server ip address

Comment: Did you get the Warning on your GRANT statement ? What is the output of  `SHOW WARNINGS;`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Similar question have already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972867/connect-on-remote-mysql-database-through-python).

- Can you connect from your local OS to your remote Database? 
  `mysql -u XXXX -h {IP} -p`
- Have you granted your client in the Database? [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-remote-database-to-optimize-site-performance-with-mysql) HowTo for this
- Create an user for the remote access
- `GRANT SELECT,DELETE,INSERT,UPDATE ON tablename.* TO 'user'@'your_local_ip';`
- `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

It's good practice not to grant all privileges for remote users (scripts)

Your local IP should be a static IP, otherwise you have allways change ip or use a dynDNS like Service.

(EDIT)
I just set up an environment:

- If you connect to an address  that does not exist or the mysql/mariadb instance is not running you get errorcode **2003**.'

`(2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'my_hostname' (61)")`

- If you're local host is not granted you get error **1130**

`(1130, "Host '213.213.213.213' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server")`

To check if you can access your remote sql server try

`mysql -h 123.123.123.123 -u username -p`

on youre local windwos machine, where 123.123.123.123 is the IP Adress of your DigitalOcean Server.

To get your public IP Adress (outside of starbucks) you can visit a Site like [this](https://www.whatismyip.com/what-is-my-public-ip-address)

If you REALLY used 0.0.0.0 as ip:
0.0.0.0 in service configuration as ip address is used to bind the service for external access. 0.0.0.0 is like a joker for every ip, but can not be used to access the server/service remotely.

Comment: Hi, I have posted my code I used for this. Please take a look at it.